# Is functional programming in Rust zero-cost?

Tags: functional-programming, rust

I've made some tests on functional style programming performance in Rust:

```
extern crate rand; // 0.5.5

use rand::Rng;

fn time(f: impl FnOnce()) -> std::time::Duration {
    let s = std::time::Instant::now();
    f();
    s.elapsed()
}

fn main() {
    let iteration = 10000000;

    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    println!(
        "while: {:?}",
        time(|| {
            let mut i = 0;
            let mut num = 0i64;
            while i < iteration {
                num += rng.gen::<i64>();
                i += 1;
            }
        })
    ); // 29.116528ms

    println!(
        "for: {:?}",
        time(|| {
            let mut num = 0i64;
            for _ in 0..iteration {
                num += rng.gen::<i64>();
            }
        })
    ); // 26.68407ms

    println!(
        "fold: {:?}",
        time(|| {
            rng.gen_iter::<i64>().take(iteration).fold(0, |x, y| x + y);
        })
    ); // 26.065936ms
}
```

I've set the optimization flag to compile it.

These three cases took nearly the same time, does that mean that functional programming in Rust is zero-cost?

Comment: Zero-cost in what sense? Zero additional cost in comparison to the manually compiled imperative code equivalent? That would assume the compiler can always inline and specialize higher order functions, including at polymorphic types, which seems hard to guarantee.

Comment: All this suggests to me is that the random number generator takes much longer than any difference between the look techniques.

Comment: Yes, LLVM optimizer can optimize iterators down to correct and fast imperative code, and yes, Rust and LLVM do a lot of inlining. I'm not that qualified, however, to tell anything about which optimization techniques are used exactly.

Comment: @dcorking That's true. In fact I have no idea in making this comparison more sensable. I don't know how to control the compiler to just optimize the correct part of the code. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Standard performance caveat** Like always, you should benchmark your code in your situations and understand what the tradeoffs are. Start with understandable code and make it faster when/if necessary.

Here are the functions, broken out and made to never inline. I also prevented the random number generator from being inlined and made the iteration count smaller for later:

```
extern crate rand; // 0.5.5

use rand::{distributions::Standard, Rng, RngCore};

const ITERATION: usize = 10000;

#[inline(never)]
fn add_manual(mut rng: impl Rng) -> i64 {
    let mut num = 0;

    let mut i = 0;
    while i < ITERATION {
        num += rng.gen::<i64>();
        i += 1;
    }

    num
}

#[inline(never)]
fn add_range(mut rng: impl Rng) -> i64 {
    let mut num = 0;

    for _ in 0..ITERATION {
        num += rng.gen::<i64>();
    }

    num
}

#[inline(never)]
fn add_fold(mut rng: impl Rng) -> i64 {
    rng.sample_iter::<i64, _>(&Standard)
        .take(ITERATION)
        .fold(0i64, |x, y| x + y)
}

#[inline(never)]
fn add_sum(mut rng: impl Rng) -> i64 {
    rng.sample_iter::<i64, _>(&Standard).take(ITERATION).sum()
}

// Prevent inlining the RNG to create easier-to-inspect LLVM IR
struct NoInlineRng<R: Rng>(R);

impl<R: Rng> RngCore for NoInlineRng<R> {
    #[inline(never)]
    fn next_u32(&mut self) -> u32 {
        self.0.next_u32()
    }
    #[inline(never)]
    fn next_u64(&mut self) -> u64 {
        self.0.next_u64()
    }
    #[inline(never)]
    fn fill_bytes(&mut self, dest: &mut [u8]) {
        self.0.fill_bytes(dest)
    }
    #[inline(never)]
    fn try_fill_bytes(&mut self, dest: &mut [u8]) -> Result<(), rand::Error> {
        self.0.try_fill_bytes(dest)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut rng = NoInlineRng(rand::thread_rng());
    let a = add_manual(&mut rng);
    let b = add_range(&mut rng);
    let c = add_fold(&mut rng);
    let d = add_sum(&mut rng);

    println!("{}, {}, {}, {}", a, b, c, d);
}
```

And the corresponding LLVM IR, from Rust 1.29.2 building in release mode:

```
; playground::add_manual
; Function Attrs: noinline uwtable
define internal fastcc i64 @_ZN10playground10add_manual17hb7f61676b41e00bfE(i64** dereferenceable(8)) unnamed_addr #4 personality i32 (i32, i32, i64, %"unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Exception"*, %"unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Context"*)* @rust_eh_personality {
start:
  br label %bb4

bb3:                                              ; preds = %bb4
  ret i64 %2

bb4:                                              ; preds = %bb4, %start
  %num.09 = phi i64 [ 0, %start ], [ %2, %bb4 ]
  %i.08 = phi i64 [ 0, %start ], [ %3, %bb4 ]
  %rng.val.val = load i64*, i64** %0, align 8
; call <playground::NoInlineRng<R> as rand_core::RngCore>::next_u64
  %1 = tail call fastcc i64 @"_ZN71_$LT$playground..NoInlineRng$LT$R$GT$$u20$as$u20$rand_core..RngCore$GT$8next_u6417h0b95e10cc642939aE"(i64* %rng.val.val)
  %2 = add i64 %1, %num.09
  %3 = add nuw nsw i64 %i.08, 1
  %exitcond = icmp eq i64 %3, 10000
  br i1 %exitcond, label %bb3, label %bb4
}
```

```
; playground::add_range
; Function Attrs: noinline uwtable
define internal fastcc i64 @_ZN10playground9add_range17h27ceded9d02ff747E(i64** dereferenceable(8)) unnamed_addr #4 personality i32 (i32, i32, i64, %"unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Exception"*, %"unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Context"*)* @rust_eh_personality {
start:
  br label %bb8

bb6:                                              ; preds = %bb8
  ret i64 %3

bb8:                                              ; preds = %bb8, %start
  %num.021 = phi i64 [ 0, %start ], [ %3, %bb8 ]
  %iter.sroa.0.020 = phi i64 [ 0, %start ], [ %1, %bb8 ]
  %1 = add nuw nsw i64 %iter.sroa.0.020, 1
  %rng.val.val = load i64*, i64** %0, align 8
; call <playground::NoInlineRng<R> as rand_core::RngCore>::next_u64
  %2 = tail call fastcc i64 @"_ZN71_$LT$playground..NoInlineRng$LT$R$GT$$u20$as$u20$rand_core..RngCore$GT$8next_u6417h0b95e10cc642939aE"(i64* %rng.val.val)
  %3 = add i64 %2, %num.021
  %exitcond = icmp eq i64 %1, 10000
  br i1 %exitcond, label %bb6, label %bb8
}
```

```
; playground::add_sum
; Function Attrs: noinline uwtable
define internal fastcc i64 @_ZN10playground7add_sum17h0910bf39c2bf0430E(i64** dereferenceable(8)) unnamed_addr #4 personality i32 (i32, i32, i64, %"unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Exception"*, %"unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Context"*)* @rust_eh_personality {
bb2.i.i.i.i:
  br label %bb2.i.i.i.i.i

bb2.i.i.i.i.i:                                    ; preds = %bb2.i.i.i.i.i, %bb2.i.i.i.i
  %1 = phi i64 [ 10000, %bb2.i.i.i.i ], [ %3, %bb2.i.i.i.i.i ]
  %accum.0.i.i.i.i.i = phi i64 [ 0, %bb2.i.i.i.i ], [ %4, %bb2.i.i.i.i.i ]
  %.val.val.i.i.i.i.i.i = load i64*, i64** %0, align 8, !noalias !33
; call <playground::NoInlineRng<R> as rand_core::RngCore>::next_u64
  %2 = tail call fastcc i64 @"_ZN71_$LT$playground..NoInlineRng$LT$R$GT$$u20$as$u20$rand_core..RngCore$GT$8next_u6417h0b95e10cc642939aE"(i64* %.val.val.i.i.i.i.i.i), !noalias !33
  %3 = add nsw i64 %1, -1
  %4 = add i64 %2, %accum.0.i.i.i.i.i
  %5 = icmp eq i64 %3, 0
  br i1 %5, label %_ZN4core4iter8iterator8Iterator3sum17hcbc4a00f32ac1feeE.exit, label %bb2.i.i.i.i.i

_ZN4core4iter8iterator8Iterator3sum17hcbc4a00f32ac1feeE.exit: ; preds = %bb2.i.i.i.i.i
  ret i64 %4
}
```

You can see that `add_manual` and `add_range` are basically the same, except for the position of `add`. `add_sum` is also similar, but it counts down from 10000 instead of counting up. There is no definition for `add_fold` because the compiler has identified that it's the exact same code as `add_sum` and combined them.

In this case, the optimizer can indeed make these basically the same. Let's use the built-in benchmarking:

```
#[bench]
fn bench_add_manual(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        let rng = rand::thread_rng();
        add_manual(rng)
    });
}

#[bench]
fn bench_add_range(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        let rng = rand::thread_rng();
        add_range(rng)
    });
}

#[bench]
fn bench_add_sum(b: &mut Bencher) {
    b.iter(|| {
        let rng = rand::thread_rng();
        add_sum(rng)
    });
}
```

The results are:

```
test bench_add_manual ... bench:      28,058 ns/iter (+/- 3,552)
test bench_add_range  ... bench:      28,349 ns/iter (+/- 6,663)
test bench_add_sum    ... bench:      29,807 ns/iter (+/- 2,016)
```

This seems pretty much the same to me. I would say, *in this case, at this point in time*, that there isn't a significant difference in the performance. However, this doesn't apply to every possible bit of code in a functional style.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, fold (reduce) can compile to the equivalent efficient hand-compiled code, and so save programmer time. Notably, recursion in a fold is in tail position, so it is merely a simpler way to write a loop.

This will not be true of all programs you write in functional style.

Comment: My answer is very short, but hopefully deserves editing later to fill it out with examples.